# C: check if all child processes have ended

Tags: c, fork, system, wait

My program uses systems calls to count number of words in a file, and I  need a way to check when all child have exited so that I can print a statement saying "x files have been counted". So I need a way to stop it from printing the print statement twice, and it should only print once at the end.

My output:

```
Child process for input_file_1.txt: word count is: 6
All 2 files have been counted
Child process for input_file_2.txt: word count is: 14
All 2 files have been counted
```

my main code (assume the wordCount function is correct):

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[]){
    int *pid;
    int parentPid, status;

    if (argc < 2){
        printf("Usage: a.out(./a.out) filename1 filename2 ..\n");
        return -1;
    }

    pid = (int*)malloc(argc-1 * sizeof(int));
    parentPid = getpid();

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0){
            if (countWord(parentPid,argv[i]) > 0)
                printf("Child process for %s: word count is: %d\n",argv[i],countWord(parentPid,argv[i]));

        }
        else{
            if(parentPid == getpid()){
                wait(&status);
                if (WIFEXITED(status) != 0)
                    printf("All %d files have been counted\n",argc - 1);
            }
        }
    }  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just have a seperate `for` loop that calls `wait` and don't print anything until that loop completes.

Comment: then I insert the print statement after the `for loop` ?

Comment: Yes that should work.

Comment: I did it and it didn't work.